# libGDX keeps saying JAVA_HOME has an incorrect directory

Tags: java, path, libgdx

I have `JAVA_HOME` set up at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1`in enviroment varibles **under user variables** but in CMD and libGDX, it is not resovled.

In CMD, java is not resovled while in libGDX the path specified is invaild for some reason. I know there is another question exactly like this but ***NONE OF THEM SOLVED MY QUESTION***.

Comment: Are you able to see correct version of java after typing java -version ?

Comment: @Sambit In cmd, `java` cannot be resolved .

Comment: What do you mean by JAVA cannot be resolved? If you have installed java properly and type java -version in windows command, you should be able to see java version details properly. Did you try to execute the command ?

Comment: @Sambit I did `java -version` in cmd and  'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. comes up

Comment: It means either java has not yet been installed properly or you did not set JAVA_HOME in windows. Go to environment variable in windows and set JAVA_HOME as key and value as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin as value.

Comment: @Sambit In User Variables, or System Variables?

Comment: In User variable.

Comment: @Sambit Same error appears. I will reinstall the JDK to see if it was not installed properly.

Comment: After setting the JAVA_HOME, open new command prompt and type java -version.

Comment: @Sambit Same Error occurs.

Comment: Remove java and reinstall and set JAVA_HOME as I suggested.

Comment: I provided complete instruction, check and install accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Java 12, refer below the documentation link.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html#GUID-C11500A9-252C-46FE-BB17-FC5A9528EAEB

Besides, follow the basic instruction about how to setup java.

1. Install Java in desired location.
2. Set Java home like JAVA_HOME as key and java installation location\bin as value in envrionment variable in Windows. I provide an example `JAVA_HOME` as key and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin` as value.
3. In the same environment variable edit the `path` which is a key and add java installation location\bin; I provide an example path as key and value as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin;`
4. Open command prompt and type java -version. You will be able to see the java version details.